# Android: how to change IP Address from within TCP Client app?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, android-asynctask, ip

I am trying to communicate between a C# TCP server, and an Android TCP client. I am new to android so used the second part of this tutorial to create the android client:
http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/07/20/android-tcp-connection-tutorial/#.V8uZISgrKUk

Everything works fine, and I can send little text messages between my phone and my computer, however this tutorial requires that the client app have the server IP hard coded into the program, and for obvious reasons this is going to cause issues if I actually wanted to make an app that uses this.

Outside of this tutorial I have added a second EditText ("@id/ipTxt") and a second button ("@id/setIp")

As I don't want to make anybody read through the whole tutorial, here are the important parts summarized:

Main Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private ListView mList;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;
    private TCPClient mTcpClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);

        //relate the listView from java to the one created in xml
        mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, arrayList);
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // connect to the server
        new connectTask().execute("");

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String message = editText.getText().toString();

                //add the text in the arrayList
                arrayList.add("c: " + message);

                //sends the message to the server
                if (mTcpClient != null) {
                    mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                }

                //refresh the list
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });

    }

    public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {

        @Override
        protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            //we create a TCPClient object and
            mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            //in the arrayList we add the messaged received from server
            arrayList.add(values[0]);
            // notify the adapter that the data set has changed. This means that new message received
            // from server was added to the list
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

TCPClient class:

```
public class TCPClient {

    private String serverMessage;
    public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.0.102"; //your computer IP address
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 4444;
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    private boolean mRun = false;

    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;

    /**
     *  Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message){
        if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
        }
    }

    public void stopClient(){
        mRun = false;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            try {

                //send the message to the server
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

                //receive the message which the server sends back
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {
                    serverMessage = in.readLine();

                    if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                    }
                    serverMessage = null;

                }

                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

My theory would be to stop the connectTask process every time the "setIp" button is clicked and create a new one, but that seems like a very inefficient way to do it, plus I don't know how I would go about doing that :(

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `SERVERIP` and `SERVERPORT` constants into non-static variables instead, and then initialize them using additional input values to your `TCPClient` constructor, or as input parameters to `AsyncTask.execute()` (which will then be passed as input parameters to your `doInBackground()` method).

Don't call `execute()` until you have first determined those values, either from your app's stored configuration, or from the user in the UI.

When you do start a new task, save the object to a variable in your main code (which you are not currently doing).  To cancel the connection, you can then call the `AsyncTask.cancel()` method on that variable.  Make sure your `connectTask.doInBackground()` and `TCPClient.run()` code checks the `AsyncTask.isCancelled()` method periodically so they can exit as soon as possible when it returns true.  This technique is mentioned in the [AsyncTask documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

After the `connectTask` object finishes running, you can create a new one with different input values.